# How to set a value in mux.Vars(request)

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

I want to set a value in `mux.Vars()` with `MatcherFunc` return true, then `handlerFun` can access to read.
But panic assignment to entry in nil map when `mux.Vars(request)["key"] = "value"`

How can I set a value:

```
domainRouter := router.MatcherFunc(func(request *http.Request, match *mux.RouteMatch) bool {
    if isOk {
        mux.Vars(request)["key"] = "value"
        return true
    }
    return false
}).Subrouter()
```

Comment: if Vars is nil you must initialize it first.

Answer (score 0):

This part of code is correct, the issue is in the place where you create `mux.NewRouter()`, it seems like your `domainRouter` is called before `mux.NewRouter()`.